# Control the size of an equation (in display mode)

Tags: equations, adjustbox

There are several ways to show an equation. I'm trying to put a big equation in display mode (i.e.: `\[ {\equation} \]`) and to keep it's dimensions within the size that is reasonable, using `adjustbox`.

This is the minimal (non) working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,final]{article}
\setlength\textwidth{42.5pc}
\setlength\columnsep{1.5pc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\\columnwidth is \the\columnwidth}. We are going to see a wonderful equation, it extends to the other column and knows no limits:
%\adjustbox{max size={\columnwidth}{\textheight},keepaspectratio,center}{
    \[
    \frac{k + l + m + n + p + q + r + t + u + v + w + x + y + z}{a + b + c + d + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + \frac{t + r + y + l + k + s}{\frac{small + characters }{are + fine}}}
    \]
%}
\end{document}
```

I have tried a number of other combinations, like `minipage`, `gather` and some other. Either it doesn't work or there are some margins that prevent the equation from expanding to the specified width (in this case `\columnwidth`).

Comment: The example is too unrealistic; could you change it into a more meaningful one?

Comment: It's ok if the equation is very small and unreadable, it's just an example. In fact, that's what I hope. The only important point is that the equation is not in inline mode, as that makes it more compact and looks different to all the other equations. Anyway, I modified the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just resize the equation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,final]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setlength\textwidth{42.5pc}
\setlength\columnsep{1.5pc}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\\columnwidth is \the\columnwidth}. We are going to see a wonderful equation, it extends to the other column and knows no limits:
\[
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{$\displaystyle
\frac{k + l + m + n + p + q + r + t + u + v + w + x + y + z}{a + b + c + d + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m + \frac{t + r + y + l + k + s}{\frac{small + characters }{are + fine}}}
$}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd give the `\splitfrac` macro, which is provided by the `mathtools` package, a try. It can be used in both the numerator and the denominator of a fraction expressions. As the following example shows, `\splitfrac` macros can be nested.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,twocolumn,final]{article}
\setlength\textwidth{42.5pc}
\setlength\columnsep{1.5pc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\textbackslash columnwidth is \the\columnwidth}. 

We are going to see a wonderful equation, it extends to the other column and knows no limits:
\[
\frac{\splitfrac{k + l + m + n + p + q + r + t}{ + u + v + w + x + y + z}}{\splitfrac{a + b + c + d + f + g + h + i + j}{ \splitfrac{+ k + l + m + t + r + y + l + k + s }{+ small + characters + are + fine}}}
\]
\end{document}
```